# C# how to bold one character in a word?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#.

I have a DataGridView, which gives me this output, among other things:

> 1000|66|EG|36|0003|AN1 |

I read this results from a xml file.

Is there any way to get just the pipes **|** bold in the DGV?

**EDIT:**

I don't want to bold a word, just the pipe and it's always the pipe, so I thougt I can "save"/"fix" the pipe | and say that is always has to be bold?

Comment: Do you think we should close as duplicate @Zohar

Comment: @ZoharPeled okay, but I don't really understand what I have to do.. I never worked with a DGV before. So I thougt I have to "fix" the pipe, because its always the pipe and no word, is there no easier way?

Comment: @JeremyThompson yes, otherwise I wouldn't vote to close as a duplicate....

Comment: @Zohar, I'm on.my mobile phone, it doesn't show that. Will close as duplicate.

Comment: Lizzy please try out the Paint_event in the duplicate, then look at the MSDN documentation.

Comment: No. By default one cell can only hve one font/formatting. - So you need to draw the text yourself. -  I have added another duplicate with example code. It shows how to add a line with separate formatting. Bolding single letters within a word will be similar but a bit harder.. - Just make sure to measure the parts to find nice values for the x positions! Note that this will be really hard to look perfect; going for a fixed font, like Consolas will help there..

Comment: You just create a DataTable or from a dB source. Then you use the `DGV.DataSource = DataTable;` then bold the cell in the paint event. Good luck :)

Comment: @Lizzy my answer is more detailed then the accepted answer in the first dupelicate. TAW's answer have a complete code sample. Please try to work with this. If you fail, ask a new question, share the code you have, and someone will probably answer it.